# How to add logging info in ER diagrams?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm cerating an application for doctor chanelling system and i'm designing ER diagram for it.So how can i add logging details to er diagram.Should i use a separate entity for logging or add logging details on customer entity as attributes??

Answer (score 0):

Better to add a new table/entity as you may wish to qualify the logging details (e.g. by date, or by user).